# Generating Multiple Documents in Batch Using Microsofts Mail merge

Tags: vba

Essentially uses Microsoft Words Mail Merge to generate documents from Excel file.

Only issue is that it opens up a bunch of documents 'Letters' whilst doing so. Not sure how to fix but good enough for now

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub MailMergeAndSave()

    Dim MainDoc As Document
    Dim DataSource As MailMergeDataSource
    Dim DataField As String
    Dim OutputFolder As String
    Dim i As Long
    
    ' Set the main Word document
    Set MainDoc = ActiveDocument
    
    ' Specify the data source (Excel file) and data field to iterate through
    Set DataSource = MainDoc.MailMerge.DataSource
    DataField = "Name" ' Replace with the actual field name
    
    ' Specify the folder to save the generated documents
    OutputFolder = "C:\Users\..." ' Replace with the desired folder path
    
    ' Loop through each record in the data source
    For i = 1 To DataSource.RecordCount
        ' Merge the data into the main document
        MainDoc.MailMerge.DataSource.ActiveRecord = i
        MainDoc.MailMerge.DataSource.FirstRecord = i
        MainDoc.MailMerge.Execute Pause:=False
        
        ' Create a new document to save the merged content
        Dim NewDoc As Document
        Set NewDoc = Documents.Add
        NewDoc.Range.FormattedText = MainDoc.Content.FormattedText
        
        ' Get the value from the "Name" field for the current record
        Dim CurrentName As String
        CurrentName = DataSource.DataFields(DataField).Value
        
        ' Generate a unique file name for the new document based on the current name
        Dim FileName As String
        FileName = OutputFolder & CurrentName & ".docx"
        
        ' Save the new document in the specified folder
        NewDoc.SaveAs2 FileName, FileFormat:=wdFormatDocumentDefault
        
        ' Close the new document without saving changes
        NewDoc.Close SaveChanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges
    Next i
    
End Sub
```